# how to play stream video in nextjs page（react project）use mediasource

Tags: reactjs, go, next.js, video-streaming

I want to provide a video stream in server and user can play video in webpage use mediaSource

here is my backend Golang code

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.Use(func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
        c.Next()
    })
    r.GET("/video", func(c *gin.Context) {
        f, _ := os.Open("./shanghai.flv")
        defer func(f *os.File) {
            err := f.Close()
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("close error")
            }
        }(f)
        fi, err := f.Stat()
        size := fi.Size()
        log.Printf("%v, 1, %v", err, size)
        contentType := "video"
        extraHeaders := map[string]string{
            "Content-Disposition": `inline; filename="shanghai.mp4"`,
        }
        c.DataFromReader(http.StatusOK, size, contentType, f, extraHeaders)
    })
    err := r.Run()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
}
```

here just return fileReader as response
nextjs code

```
'use client'

import {createElement, useEffect, useState} from "react";

function Video() {

    const [video, setVideo] = useState(null)
    useEffect(() => {

        const mimeCodec = 'video/x-flv; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"';
        const myMediaSource = new MediaSource();
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(myMediaSource)
        let videoRef = createElement('video', {
            id: 'my-video',
            width: 400,
            controls: true,
            src: url
        })
        setVideo(videoRef)
        myMediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', () => {
            const videoSourceBuffer = myMediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);

            videoSourceBuffer.addEventListener('error', console.log);
            fetch('http://localhost:8080/video').then((response) => {
                return response.arrayBuffer();
            }).then((videoData) => {
                videoSourceBuffer.appendBuffer(videoData);
            });
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {video}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Video
}
```

I have tried flv.js and video.js those cannot play stream video
I want know where should I change the nextjs code, besides VLC Player can play this video via http://localhost:8080/video